# “lettuce" a uncountable or uncountable noun?

Tags: vocabulary

Is the word "*lettuce*" an uncountable noun or countable noun ?

Comment: It depends on the context. Please supply some.

Comment: Also, when you edit your question, please include what you found when researching in dictionaries (there are a number available online).

Answer (score 2):

[Lettuce](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lettuce) is an uncountable noun. Its most common classifiers are "heads of lettuce" and "leaves of lettuce."

Comment: But I can buy "a lettuce" from the supermarket. It might be that that’s a colloquialism or a contraction of "head of lettuce" or it could be context dependant as suggested in the comments. Do you have any references that would clarify? (Welcome to ELU, by the way!).

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard anyone say "a lettuce" before (AmE). It's always "a head of lettuce" (or "a bag of lettuce," "some lettuce," "a lettuce leaf," etc.)

Comment: Lettuce is used countably in British English. We can say 'there are five lettuces on the table'. During a shortage, The Times reported that "Tesco stores are displaying notices that say customers can buy only three lettuces. "

Comment: As a Brit, I don't understand what "head of lettuce" means.  I assume it means a single lettuce?

Comment: @TrevorD I think it is the part that's above ground (i.e. not the roots). I added a source to show that it can be used as an uncountable or countable noun. So, technically the answer is correct (it doesn't say it cannot be use countably).

Comment: @JJJ Thanks.  The bit above ground is also what we Brits generally mean when referring to "a lettuce" (which is also what I meant by "a single lettuce" - I didn't think about the roots!).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for that! It's always fascinating to learn yet another distinction between British and American English.

Comment: I have seen "heads of lettuce" used in Britain. I suspect it is mainly used by specialists such as growers, supermarket and grocery retailers, etc